# Security inheritance for Areas?

Tags: inheritance, area

I've used TFS for quite some time now and I never noticed this behavior. I do the following:

1. Create a new Area for a team: "TestArea"
2. Add two persons to the security settings of this area.
   Person A) should be allowed to do anything in this area.
   Person B) has everything set to "deny"
3. Create a new area under "TestArea" called "SubArea"

My expectation:
Person A ist still allowed to do everything in the "SubArea", while Person B still has set everything to "deny" at "SubArea".

Is there really no security inheritance for Areas? I don't have any "inherit security" checkbox either, like I have at the source control settings or in like any other security setting dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to answer my own question:

There actually is an inheritance, it's just not shown in the dialog. So in my example Person B still is denied to do anything, but if you check the security, then Person B won't show up.